# Integration of a function + Mean value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a practice question that goes as follows:

Let 
$$f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
be a continuous function . show that there exists c in [0,1] such that

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = f(c)$$

I'm pretty sure that I'm going to use the mean value theorem here. But I'm not sure how it fits in.

Please be as elaborate as possible, I was told this is a particularly important question to prepare for my Real analysis final!!

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x):[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ be the function defined by 
$$F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt.$$

We have that $F(0) = 0$, and that $F$ is differentiable with derivative $f(x)$ by the fndamental theorem of calculus. By the mean value theorem there is a $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $$F'(c) = f(c) =\frac{F(1) - F(0)}{1-0} = \int_0^1f(x)dx.$$

Comment: Straight from the definitions! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[0,1]$ the it's bounded and attains their extremes $M=\sup f$ and $ m=\inf f$ and we have
$$m=\int_0^1mdx\le\alpha=\int_0^1f(x)dx\le \int_0^1Mdx=M$$
now apply the intermediate value theorem: there's $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=\alpha$.

Comment: nice argument .